# Check if a value in a df exist in another dataframe and add column

Tags: r, dataframe, rscript

Both fairly large 
For example :

Df1

```
Name name2  code2 code3
A    1      2     3
B    1      2     3
C    1      2     3
```

Df2

```
Name      lat           lon
A         5             6
C         1             2
```

I want to compare df1 with df2, If match add in the (`lat lon`) col to df1

Df1

```
Name name 2 code2 code3  lat    lon
A    1     2     3      5      6
B    1     2     3
C    1     2     3      1      2
```

I have tried

```
test <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Name', all = TRUE)
```

However it said that column names 'name' 'name1' are duplicated in the result. ( please assume that changing the column name is not an option )

I also tried a for loop

```
For( i in 1: nrow(df1)) {
      If ( df1$`Name`[I] %in% df2$Name) {
            Df1$lat[I] = df2$lat 
      }
}
```

However I do not know how to get the matched lat and lon to add to df1. Any help? Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be all.x = TRUE ?

Comment: I have a column with a similar name so it still gives me the error that column names are duplicated in the result

Comment: `library(dplyr)` and left join the two table `left_join(Df1, Df2)`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)` works fine, make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'Name1',by.y = 'Name', all = TRUE)
```

where by.x is df1 in this case and by.y is df2. It helps you to merge by columns containing the same data but having different names. Good luck!